# How to show a tweet popup in Android (like in iOS using SLComposeViewController)

Tags: android, ios, twitter, slcomposeviewcontroller

Coming from an `iOS` background, I am trying to understand how to show a simple prefilled Twitter popup in `Android` to the user.

With `iOS`/`Swift`, I would simply do the following:

```
if let vc = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter) {
    vc.setInitialText("Hi there!")
    present(vc, animated: true)
} else {
    print("Twitter account not available")
}
```

I went through several tutorials and posts on SO, but I am a bit confused with `TwitterAuthConfig`, the `TWITTER_KEY`/`TWITTER_SECRET` and all this stuff. Is there an easy way to do so like in iOS ?

Thank you.